# How to determine if a .resx file is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, resx

I've inherited a number of ASP.Net C# projects that mix MVC and forms.  Several projects have .resx files in App_GlobalResources.  My guess is that the files were related to .aspx forms that were converted to MVC.

I can think of two strategies for determining whether the files are in use:

1)  Remove and see what happens.  Do missing .resx files cause run-time or compile-time errors?

2)  Work backwards from the files and see what uses them.  Not exactly sure what to look for though.  String searches have come up empty.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I like option 1, but don't remove it - just change it's Build Action to `None`.  That way it's easier to undo if it turns out it is needed.  Whether it causes a Build error (hopefully!) or a Runtime error depends on how it was consumed.  Unfortunately, I suspect you are more likely to get the runtime error, which isn't a good way to check for use.  And even more unfortunate, you will only get a runtime error at the point of the code that actually tries to access a value from the RESX.  If it isn't used in your site very much, tjem it might be hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to search for the name of the resource files. E.g. if the Resourcefile is called MyGlobalResource.resx then you can search for MyGlobalresource. If it does not come up anywhere, I think you can be safe to remove it.

Comment: This does seem to work with ctrl-f on the entire solution for the old resx files.

Results of the search:
C:\Code\MailingPreviewTabs.aspx(41):  <mv:NotificationLabel ID="MessageNotificationLabel" runat="server" ResourceClass="MailingResources" />
C:\Code\MailingPreviewTabs.aspx.cs(195):        var confirmationMessage = GetGlobalResourceObject("MailingResources", "DeleteConfirmation").ToString();

Comment: I also searched for the data element names.  Fortunately none of the resource files had many defined.